# How to write gnom sort in prolog?

Tags: sorting, prolog

It's my first time with Prolog programming and I have issues with [gnome sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort), I've read it's similar to insert and bubble sort, but I have no idea how to connect them.

```
gnome_sort(List,Sorted):-g_sort(List,[],Sorted). 

g_sort([],Acc,Acc). 
g_sort([H|T],Acc,Sorted):-insert(H,Acc,NAcc),g_sort(T,NAcc,Sorted). 


last_element(X,[X]).
last_element(X,[_|O]):-last_element(X,O).
   
insert(X, last_element(P,[Y|T]),[Y|NT]):-X>P,g_sort(Y,P,NT). 
insert(X,[Y|T],[X,Y|T]):-X=<Y.
insert(X,[],[X]).
```

I have something like this but it doesn't work :((((((((

Answer (score 1):

Note that what you're implementing is not the real Gnome sort but rather something more like the "optimization" noted on the Wikipedia page which is a completely different algorithm that is an insertion sort and has nothing to do with Gnome sort itself.

Anyway, your general approach works, but your implementation of `insert/3` is broken. This is a predicate that should only insert an element into a list that is already assumed to be sorted. This predicate should never refer to `g_sort`: You don't want to freshly sort a list, only insert one element. You also don't need to refer to refer to the list's last element.

The only choice that `insert/3` needs to make in a given situation is: is `X` greater than the first element of the sorted list or not? You already handle two cases correctly: Where the list is empty, and where `X =< Y`.

Only one clause of your `insert/3` needs to change:

```
insert(X, [Y | Ys], [Y | XYs]) :-
    X > Y,
    insert(X, Ys, XYs).
```

If `X > Y`, this "skips" `Y` and looks for the correct insertion position in the rest of the list.

For comparison, your clause looked like this:

```
insert(X, last_element(P,[Y|T]),[Y|NT]):-X>P,g_sort(Y,P,NT).
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do here, maybe you were going for a "function call" to `last_element`? Remember that Prolog has no function calls. If you write something like `last_element(A, B)` in a clause head, that refers to a term of the shape `last_element(A, B)`, not to a "result" of "evaluating" the term `last_element(A, B)`.

(Also, do you see how I put each goal on a separate line and used spaces around operators and after commas? You should do that too. Prolog is already hard enough to read when it's nicely formatted, you shouldn't make it even harder with bad formatting.)

For whatever it's worth, a real Gnome sort in Prolog would look like this:

```
gnomesort(List, Sorted) :-
    gnomesort([], List, Sorted).

gnomesort(Left, [], Sorted) :-
    reverse(Left, Sorted).
gnomesort([], [R | Rs], Sorted) :-
    gnomesort([R], Rs, Sorted). 
gnomesort([L | Ls], [R | Rs], Sorted) :-
    R @>= L, 
    gnomesort([R, L | Ls], Rs, Sorted).
gnomesort([L | Ls], [R | Rs], Sorted) :-
    R @< L,
    gnomesort(Ls, [R, L | Rs], Sorted).
```